# How to redirect values from top command to a file in Mac OSX

Tags: osx-lion, top

All,
I want to extract values from top for plotting purposes.  I'm currently using the following command

```
top -l 0 -s 1  -pid 12345 -stats rsize | awk 'NR%13==0'
```

When I run this , I get the expected output. But when I try to redirect the output to a file by running the following:

```
top -l 0 -s 1  -pid 299 -stats rsize | awk 'NR%13==0' > output.txt
```

it doesn't work. What should I do to redirect the output to a file?

I'm on a Mac OSX(Lion)

Comment: It seems that batch mode (-b) is not implemented on OS X. You could set larger value for -l (say "-l 10"), but you won't be able to see the output until after the script is done, e.g. "tail -f output.txt" won't work for monitoring.

Comment: @lupincho: the only problem is awk buffering.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your expression is rigth, but be aware that awk buffers its output. So, adding `fflush(stdout)` to your awk part will help.

```
top -l 0 -s 1  -pid 299 -stats rsize | awk 'NR%13==0; fflush(stdout)' > output.txt
```