# How to save the output from top/atop

Tags: top

I wanted to know if there a way to save the output from top or atop commands into a textfile for later processing.

`atop|top > output.txt` is not really working at both top and atop keep running in the background.

edit:

OS: RHEL 6

other attempts: `top | awk 'fflush(stdout)'`

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to redirect values from top command to a file in Mac OSX](http://superuser.com/questions/391565/how-to-redirect-values-from-top-command-to-a-file-in-mac-osx)

Comment: not quite, I can't seem to be able to get this working on my RedHat box

Comment: Please edit your question to include which OS and version you are using, as well as adding a complete list of what you've tried already (and the results).

Answer (score 1):

Found the way to it in top is:

```
top -n 1
```

the -n specifies the number of iterations you want top to perform, still interested on how to accomplish the same with atop.

Answer (score 0):

For atop it is:

atop -r /var/log/atop/atop_20180204 -PALL
or

## take 5 samples 10 seconds apart

atop -PALL 10 5